# For each row return the column index and name of non-NA value

Tags: r, na

I have data frame where each row contain one non-`NA` value.

```
ED1 ED2 ED3 ED4 ED5 
1   NA  NA  NA  NA 
NA  NA  1   NA  NA 
NA  1   NA  NA  NA 
NA  NA  NA  NA  1
```

For each row, I want to get the index and name of the column containing the non-`NA` value, i.e.:

Indices: `c(1, 3, 2, 5)`, and their corresponding column names: `c("ED1" "ED3" "ED2" "ED5")`

Comment: if I understand correctly, your expected output should be 1, 3, 2, 5, given your input.

Comment: In that case, `library(tidyr) ; library(dplyr) ; gather(df) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% select(key)`

Comment: @scoa Yes, in second table I've set random numbers from this range 1..5. But the meaning is to transfer factors in one column. And now it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use an `apply()` loop here.  You could use `max.col()` in combination with a negated call to `is.na()`.

```
max.col(!is.na(df))
# [1] 1 3 2 5
```

That gives us the column numbers where the 1s are.  To get the column names, we can use that in a vector subset of the `names()` of the data frame.

```
names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df))]
# [1] "ED1" "ED3" "ED2" "ED5"
```

So we can get the desired data frame, with factor column, by doing

```
data.frame(EDU = names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df))])
#   EDU
# 1 ED1
# 2 ED3
# 3 ED2
# 4 ED5
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ED1 = c(1, NA, NA, NA), ED2 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA), 
    ED3 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA), ED4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), ED5 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1)), .Names = c("ED1", "ED2", "ED3", "ED4", "ED5"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame( ED1 = c(  1, NA, NA, NA),
                  ED2 = c( NA, NA, 1 , NA),
                  ED3 = c( NA,  1, NA, NA),
                  ED4 = c( NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  ED5 = c( NA, NA, NA,  1)  )

df_new <- data.frame( EDU = as.factor(apply(df,1,which.min)) )
levels(df_new$EDU) <- paste0("ED",levels(df_new$EDU))
```

.

```
> df
  ED1 ED2 ED3 ED4 ED5
1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA
2  NA  NA   1  NA  NA
3  NA   1  NA  NA  NA
4  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
> df_new
  EDU
1 ED1
2 ED3
3 ED2
4 ED5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
 v1 <- names(df)[+(!is.na(df)) %*% seq_along(df)]
 v1
 #[1] "ED1" "ED3" "ED2" "ED5"

 data.frame(EDU=v1)
```

---

Or using `pmax`

```
names(df)[do.call(pmax, c(df *col(df), list(na.rm=TRUE)))]
#[1] "ED1" "ED3" "ED2" "ED5"
```

Comment: Thank you, @akrun! But but I encountered the another difficulty. Some rows in my source table have no data (all columns in some rows are NA). How could I filter this rows and set also NA or another new factor to the EDU dataframe?

Comment: Your method works with NA! :) First I've made `df1 <- names(df)[do.call(pmax, c(df *col(df), list(na.rm=TRUE)))]` . Next `sourcetable$EDU <- as.factor (df1)`. So that the solution came in the two lines.

Comment: @IlyaRusin  If there are rows with all NA, you can filter it by `!rowSums(!is.na(df))`